# Resampling data to show only data as of the last date of the month

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have data similar to:

| Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/5/22 | 4 | 5 |
| 1/6/22 | 8 | 3 |
| 1/8/22 | 1 | 5 |
| 2/10/22 | 4 | 8 |
| 2/28/22 | 6 | 4 |
| 3/15/22 | 6 | 0 |
| 3/21/22 | 0 | 0 |
| 3/25/22 | 5 | 7 |

I want to retain only rows with the last date of the month, similar to below:

| Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/8/22 | 1 | 5 |
| 2/28/22 | 6 | 4 |
| 3/25/22 | 5 | 7 |

I tried using the following code:

```
df.resample("M").last()
```

However, I get the following error:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

But my index is set as Date column which is passed through the datetime function as below:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a monthly period (convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)) and [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
# convert to datetime
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)

# get index of last day per monthly period
out = df.loc[date.groupby(date.dt.to_period('M')).idxmax()]
```

output:

```
      Date  A  B
2   1/8/22  1  5
4  2/28/22  6  4
7  3/25/22  5  7
```

*NB. if you expect more than one "last date" row per month, use:*

```
out = df.loc[date.isin(date.groupby(date.dt.to_period('M')).max())]
```

##### if `Date` is the index

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df.index.to_series(), dayfirst=False)

out = df.loc[date.groupby(date.dt.to_period('M')).idxmax()]
```